# Got 3 columns of interest, need to show their graph, using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 3 metric columns that are of interest:

```
OPENED_AT, READ_AT, CLICKED_AT
```

each of which is a DATETIME stating actions made by the users.

The objective is to show a graph throughout the year segmented into weeks, showing how many users opened, read throughout the content and clicked a button.
Pretty much like this:

[image: Sample graph]

My main objective is to stay lean and efficient throughout the code and queries. I'd like to practically divide each color (metric) by the week.
I would like to refrain from using 3 seperate SELECT queries with a different `GROUP BY (WEEK_OPENED_AT)`, then `GROUP BY (WEEK_READ_AT)` and `GROUP BY (WEEK_CLICKED_AT)`.

My guess was this would work:

```
SELECT WEEK(`OPENED_AT`) AS WEEK_OPENED_AT, COUNT(`OPENED_AT`) AS 
COUNT_OPENED_AT from `tbl_usage` GROUP BY WEEK_OPENED_AT
```

then

```
SELECT WEEK(`READ_AT`) AS WEEK_READ_AT, COUNT(`READ_AT`) AS COUNT_READ_AT 
from `tbl_usage` GROUP BY WEEK_READ_AT
```

then the last

```
SELECT WEEK(`CLICKED_AT`) AS WEEK_CLICKED_AT, COUNT(`CLICKED_AT`) AS 
COUNT_CLICKED_AT from `tbl_usage` GROUP BY WEEK_CLICKED_AT
```

Can I accomplish that result that with a single SELECT?
Thanks upfront

PS: Maybe an option would be to add a running number like 1..52 representing week numbers, so that group by can segment all the same?
The problem is that weeks can pass by without any any clicks, but with many say opens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If the columns you show are in the same rows (i.e. same row has both CLICKED_AT and READ_AT values), then you'd need separate counts / joins.

I'd recommend using a recursive CTE to generate the week dates first, then individual CTEs to get each of the aggregate values, and then outer-join those to the week dimension, coalescing NULLs to zeroes.

Example:

```
WITH RECURSIVE all_weeks(weekStart) AS (
    SELECT CAST('2018-12-31' AS date)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATE_ADD(weekStart, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
     FROM all_months
     WHERE DATE_ADD(weekStart, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) < '2019-04-01'
    )
, op_cnt as (SELECT 
    SUBDATE('OPENED_AT', WEEKDAY('OPENED_AT')) AS WEEK_OPENED_AT, 
    COUNT('OPENED_AT') AS COUNT_OPENED_AT 
  from `tbl_usage` GROUP BY WEEK_OPENED_AT
)
SELECT weekStart, COALESCE(COUNT_OPENED_AT , 0) as cnt_Opens
from all_weeks
LEFT JOIN op_cnt ON (weekStart = WEEK_OPENED_AT)
```